# Problems after updating my Galaxy S3 to 4.1.1: Display randomly comes on for a few seconds

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I updated my Galaxy S3 (GT-i9300) to JellyBean 4.1.1, now the display randomly comes on for a few seconds, then goes off. When pushing the "unlock" button it now gets a disgusting thick red border around the edges of the display which flashes on and off, this also happens when one activates some of the apps (not sure if particular ones or just random).

When accessing some of the standard apps I now get these irritating "help" popups and clicking the "don't display this again" hasn't turned these off; they reappear with this box unchecked; there seem to be a couple of other things as well, but haven't established exactly what yet.

Rebooting several times didn't fix any of this; I haven't taken the battery out yet, and, the update manager just says the system is up to date, so a reload seems to be out of the question.

As one can expect this is fairly irritating on a fairly new high end cellphone.
Any ideas of what happened?  Any fixes for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please could you check the developer options in `System Settings -> Developer Options`? It sounds like some are enabled, you should turn them all off using the toggle switch at the top, or just untick them all.

Answer (score 0):

To stop red border showing go to **System Settings > Developer options**, uncheck **Strict mode enabled** and restart the device.